# Why does an apostophe in my Java String appear as `&#039;` in my HTML?

Tags: java, html, string, escaping

Why does the Java string:

```
"God's wrath"
```

appear in HTML as

```
God&#039;s wrath
```

How to avoid this?

Comment: why would you want to avoid it?

Comment: Does it appear that way in the source of your HTML or in the page view? If it's the source then, yes, why would you want to avoid it?

Answer (score 7):

This character is escaped to prevent XSS if the resulting string is used in HTML attribute quoted with `'`. See [OWASP XSS Prevention Cheat Sheet](http://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_%28Cross_Site_Scripting%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet).

I don't think it's a good idea to disable such security precautions, since they don't harm the normal behaviour.

Answer (score 4):

Just like the '<', '>', and other characters, the quote is replaced by that code to avoid nasty surprises when the browser is rendering the page. Take a look at [this](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_entities.asp) list by W3Schools for a complete list of codes and their respective symbol.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using JSTL the c:out tag has an escapeXml attribute, you can set it to false to avoid encoding characters.

Answer (score 1):

Special characters appear as ampersand escaped numbers because they mean something in HTML. In this case the ' is used to start a string literal. if you want it to actually show the ' then you have to replace it with the escaping. That's the why.

I don't know why you'd want to avoid it though.